# MongoDB query to retrieve all matching ids from array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I would like to retrieve documents from the DB that match a manager Id and employee  ids which comes in an array.

```
SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE MANAGER_ID=<manager_id> AND EMPLOYEE_ID IN [....]
```

Here my code:

```
var query = [
    {             
        "$and": [ 
            {"employee": { $in : employees}}, 
            {"manager": ObjectId(managerId)}
        ]
    }
];
```

But in actuality, the query returns all documents in the model.
Please advise.

Comment: I think problem is with array `[]`... It should be `var query =  {             
        "$and": [ 
            {"employee": { $in : employees}}, 
            {"manager": ObjectId(managerId)}
        ]
    }`

Comment: Thank you! it works, please post as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In find query first parameter should be an object not an array

```
var query = {
  "$and": [
    { "employee": { $in : employees }},
    { "manager": ObjectId(managerId) }
  ]
}

db.collection.find(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `elemMatch` to get matching the array's one or more keys

```
   ArrayFieldName: {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "employee": {
                        $in: employees
                    },
                    "manager": ObjectId(managerId)
                }
     }
```